# Extract message from JSON response

Tags: php, json

I get a response result like this:

```json
Server error: `POST result  a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
{"message": "Internal Error", "details": "Command Failed - Object Exists"}
```

How can I fetch the response message only from this result?

Comment: The entire response body is `Server error: `POST result  a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
{"message": "Internal Error", "details": "Command Failed - Object Exists"}` ? Or it's just `{"message": "Internal Error", "details": "Command Failed - Object Exists"}`? It wasn't clear, and you didn't give any context really. See [ask]